# setup MPRemoteCommandCenter in watchOS Now Playing with WKAudioFilePlayer

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-5

I'm working on an app that play audio in Apple Watch; All working fine from inside the app.
I'm trying to setup the `MPRemoteCommandCenter` in 'Now Playing' to change the *next/prev track* to *skipForward/skipBackward* and to add a handler for the pause command.

**Nothing change in Now Playing commands the the handler not being trigged.**

Below a snippet code:

**Play method**

```
var player: WKAudioFilePlayer!
    @IBAction func play() {


        let avSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        try! avSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, policy: .longForm, options: [])

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "mp3")!
        let item = WKAudioFilePlayerItem(asset: WKAudioFileAsset(url: url))
        player = WKAudioFilePlayer(playerItem: item)


        do {
            try avSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            player.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }

    }
```

**Remote controls setup method:**

```
func setupRemoteControls() {
        // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

        commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.preferredIntervals = [NSNumber(value: 15)]
        commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            // skip forward
            return .success
        }
        commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.isEnabled = true


        commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.preferredIntervals = [NSNumber(value: 15)]
        commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            // skip backword
            return .success
        }
        commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = true


        // Add handler for play Command
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            self.player.play()
            return .success
        }

        // Add handler for Pause Command
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
            self.player.pause()
            return .success
        }

    }
```

- I'm calling `self.setupRemoteControls()` in `awake` method. Also I tried to move the setup to the `ExtensionDelegate -> applicationDidFinishLaunching`

Apple references I used:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/504/

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/RefiningTheUserExperience/RefiningTheUserExperience.html

---

**:: UPDATE ::**

I found when using the `AVAudioPlayer` instead of `WKAudioFilePlayer` the setup for `MPRemoteCommandCenter` working fine.

The problem that I don't use local audio files!.. I stream 'm3u8' files using wowza which worked only with `WKAudioFilePlayer`.
And if I tried to stream using `AVAudioPlayer` I get this error

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

So my issue now to get `MPRemoteCommandCenter` being configured while still using `WKAudioFilePlayer`, or find a way to stream using `AVAudioPlayer` ??